# SPI between myRio and Arduino

Tags: arduino, spi

I am using SPI to connect MyRio to Arduino. The code for myRio is in LabView and for Arduino I use the IDE

myRio is sending continuously a value to the Arduino to indicate that it's running, the question is if the labview program stopped how can I detect it?
this is the code I have, I tried to use if(rx == null) but it did not work

```
#include <SPI.h>

const int slaveSelectPin = 10;

void SlaveInit(void) {
  // Initialize SPI pins.
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
  pinMode(slaveSelectPin, OUTPUT);
  // Enable SPI as slave.
  SPCR = (1 << SPE);
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SlaveInit();

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(1){
    digitalWrite(slaveSelectPin, LOW);
   byte rx = SPI.transfer(0);
        Serial.println(rx);
          if(rx == null) 
                  Serial.println("Myrio stopped"); 
}

}
```